# How to keep data constant in cells when reference cell is changed?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am working on a project with a number of different retail sites that range in completeness.

In Column A, I want to record which phase of the project a site is on (ranging from 1-3).  In Columns B (phase 1), C (phase 2), and D (phase 3) I want the dates to appear when a change is made in column A.

**Now here is the part that I am stuck on:**
How can i make it so that the date in column B does not change when I change column A from phase 1 to phase 2, and from phase 2 to phase 3.
For example, Column A row 1 is marked as 1 and when this is done the date of 11/8/2017 appears in Column B.
Which function or code can I use so that when I change column A to 2 (a week later), the date in column B remains the same and the date is recorded.

If anyone has any idea I would truly appreciate the support.

Comment: What have you already tried and where did you run into a problem? Please keep in mind that SO is not a "write all the code for me" website.

Comment: You can use the `Worksheet_Change` event to fire some code when you update column A.  Use `Intersect` to check the required cell is being updated.  Check that the cell is either empty or one lower than the value you're entering when it's updated (so you're not duplicating phases).  Use something like `Target.Offset(,1) = Date` to enter todays date one cell to the right of the changed cell, use `Application.EnableEvents=False` to stop the code continually firing when it changes a cell value.

Comment: I wasn't looking for someone to write it. Just if it can be done, and the kind of formula or coding to use (i have only recently started take classes on VBA coding.

Comment: I am trying to use an if function with circular referencing, which works fine until the value in column A is changed..

Answer (score 0):

After the date in column B is initially populated, copy and paste it back into the same cell using values only. This way it merely has the value with no formula. This is in VBScript but it gives you the idea.

```
' Select the applicable cell in B
 objExcel.Cells(2, 2).Select

'Copy the data in column B
 objExcel.Selection.Copy

'Put the cursor in column B   
 objExcel.Range("B2").Select

'Paste the value
 objExcel.Selection.PasteSpecial -4163, -4142, False, False
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try it now.

Comment: Please don't use that `.Select` madness. `objExcel.Cells(2, 2).Copy` achieves the exact same thing as the first two instructions. `objExcel.Range("B2").PasteSpecial -4163, -4142, False, False` achieves the exact same thing as the last two instructions. Using `.Select` and `.Activate`, and coding late-bound without IntelliSense against the `Selection` is one of the primary causes of bugs.. and SO questions.

Comment: The gist of the answer lies in copying and pasting the value into the cell to be left with no formula. Doing that will achieve what the OP needs. Specifically how they do it programmatically will best be left up to them.